# HBase: Scan for Row Keys containing a String

Tags: hadoop, nosql, hbase

I have a HBase table containing the following row key format:

```
<salt>:<id>#<category>#<class>

000001:1234#AAAAAAAAAA#BBBBBBB
000001:2345#CCCCCCCCCC#DDDDDDD
000002:1234#EEEEEEEEEE#FFFFFFF
...
```

I'd like to make a `Scan` on the Row Keys and get all the rows where the key contains `id=1234`. Is it possible to add a `regex` or a `SubstringComparator` to the `PrefixFilter` (the `PrefixFilter` worked perfectly for the `id` filtering before I added the `salt` value in front of the key)?

Or are there other possibilities to search for this key part?

Answer (score 2):

You need a `RowFilter` with `RegexStringComparator`:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.CompareFilter;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.RegexStringComparator;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.RowFilter;

RowFilter filter = new RowFilter(
    CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL, 
    new RegexStringComparator("your_regexp")
);
```